# Disadvantages of modifying layout based on screen width as detected by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a web site I'm designing to work well with the most common screen resolutions, and I'm considering the following way of accomplishing that goal.

-Design css classes appropriate to each resolution (specifying properties like width and position).

-Code HTML with elements styled using css classes appropriate to default resolution.

-Detect screen width using javascript (screen.width property).

-If the detected width is close enough to a more suitable resolution, use javascript to dynamically remove all css classes appropriate to default resolution and replace them with css classes appropriate to more suitable resolution.

Are there any major problems with this approach?

Comment: An alternative to consider is using `@media` queries in pure CSS. The one advantage with that approach is that it would work if JS was disabled/unavailable.

Comment: Have you considered doing it entirely with CSS using media queries?  See http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/04/targeted-css/ for some info.

Comment: I agree, however detecting the device with @media queries seems to be pretty unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it as you wrote in your question. There's an easier solution.

Use [media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/), and a JavaScript polyfill to make it work in browsers that don't have native support.

I like [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

Answer (score 0):

The golden rule is: never use Javascript to style webpages. There are some exceptions where you can use JS to build a dynamic UI/layout usually for complex applications, but whenever possible, avoid it.

Create a SINGLE set of CSS rules that work with all resolutions. You can use media selectors if you want to target extreme resolutions like mobile etc, but for all other cases use a single layout.

Comment: so what are the reasons behind your recommendation?

Comment: @LynHeadley Use the appropriate tools for different tasks. Javascript is intended to be used to for functionality, not presentation. Not only will you spend more time doing stuff that can easily be achieved with regular HTML/CSS, but your site loading speeds will be noticeably longer. Especially on mobile devices. Don't try to stick JS where it doesn't belong.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa Your golden rule is only valid for public facing websites which must support non-JS browsers. However, for web applications that are not public facing, it is much cleaner design to have the client (JS) generate the HTML, since the server does not need to know what format the data is going to be displayed in (XML, JSON, HTML, Swing, Objective-C) I have been working for 12 years designing web apps that are purely JS based, the app server doesn't send a single line of HTML.

Comment: @JuanMendes I have no idea why have you been misusing Javascript that bad the last 12 years. Even if you don't send a single line of HTML over from the server doesn't mean you shouldn't/couldn't use HTML/CSS to design the UI. The fact that that it's not a public service does not make up for malpractice, internal applications should follow the same standards, after all the users are the same people who use public web services. Only dynamic parts should be JS-generated, and even in those cases it should be based on HTML templates

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa: Your smart ass comment is uncalled for, feel free to express your opinion, but understand it is **your** opinion. Facebook, Gmail, Yahoo mail all **mis** use JS to generate the HTML. The JS acts on the HTML, so it has to know the internals of how the HTML was designed, they are tightly coupled. It's much better design to keep them together. Of course I use templates, but they are JS based templates, like https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js

Answer (score 0):

http://cssgrid.net/

Media queries as noted above work great!

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about javascript not working, here's an alternate solution than using media queries. Sometimes To do what you want you have to change The HTML. And media queries does not do that. You can link to a totally new HTML page with the code below.

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 550px)' href='css/style300.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 551px) and (max-width: 1024px)' href='css/style600.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1920px)' href='css/style800.css' />
```

Comment: This isnt linking to new html page. This is switching CSS styles based on screen width. Not too different from using media query blocks in css file